# sort one column in matrix and then order other column according to sorted column in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix `m`, I want to sort the first column and then change the order of second and third column according to the sorted first column. how can I get it in R?

```
x = rnorm(50, 0, 1)
y = rbinom(50, 1, .5)
z = runif(50, -1, 1)
m = matrix(c(x, y, z), ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order()` to determine the appropriate ordering.

```
set.seed(101)
m <- cbind(rnorm(50, 0, 1),
           rbinom(50, 1, .5)
           runif(50, -1, 1))
ord <- order(m[,1])
m2 <- m[ord,]
```

(You can do it in one step as `m[order(m[,1]),]` if you want.)
`plyr::arrange` is handy for data frames.